# How Do I Format A Connection String to Analysis Server in RMDX?

Tags: r, mdx

Sorry in advance for asking a very basic/newbie question, but I'm trying to use RMDX to query some data from a Microsoft Analysis Server from RStudio. RMDX is the only package I've been able to successfully install. I've also tried adding X4R w install_github but had some difficulty (and in any case X4R also seems to use a URL as the connection string), and I've tried adding olapR from my RClient library to my R 3.5.2 library, but I get an error about it being made for a version of R with different internals.

RMDX takes a URL as a connection string and I don't know how to format the data connection... correctly, I guess? I've only used sql with RODBC in R before, and setting up a data source via ODBC Data Source Administrator doesn't work for the data warehouse.

Obviously I'm missing a lot of basics/theory/fundamentals so I'm just kind of shooting in the dark, but I've tried "localhost//[server-name]," "https://[server-name]," and copying the connection string used for some of the microsoft bi dashboards that connect to the same data warehouse that I want to query, and none work. Does anyone know how to solve this issue, or can anyone suggest an alternative way of executing MDX queries from RStudio? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting on a similar route like you - I have ended up writing a powershell script that connects to the MS SSAS or OLAP Cube via its "URL" (usually you will use the URL string that has the 'msmdpump.dll' mentioned in it somewhere - usually at the end of it - as the $con or connection string). After that (meaning in the ps script more precisely it is a module) I heavily rely on the `AdomdClient` object and its properties, something along these lines

```
#establish SSAS ADOMD Client and open connection
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(\"Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient\") | Out-Null;
```

\

```
echo 'Connecting to Database/Cube via Powershell module!'
$con = new-object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection($connectionString)
$con.Open() 
$command = new-object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdCommand($MDXquery, $con)
$dataAdapter = new-object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdDataAdapter($command)
$ds = new-object System.Data.DataSet
#fetch data
echo 'fill data container w cube data'
$dataAdapter.Fill($ds)
$con.Close(); 
....
```

After that I call this ps script via `system2(command = "powershell",...)` from within R with the various connectionstring, MDX (query) and so on parameters, save the result in a temp folder as a csv file and then load that back into my R session again.

Hope that helps.